# Was Obi-Wan Completely Out of Touch While on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars

After Luke and Leia were born and Obi-Wan was watching Luke grow up on Tatooine, was he able to keep in touch with any of his old contacts?  Especially with Bail Organa, who was raising Leia?  Was he able to keep track of Leia's progress and growth while she was living on Aldaraan?  Or was there anyone else he was able to communicate with?  Or did he stay incommunicado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, and intentionally so

In the Disney canon novel Ahsoka, Bail Organa muses that Obi-Wan wished to avoid contact with him:

> He debated sending a message to Obi-Wan but almost immediately
> dismissed the idea. They had agreed to no contact, except in the
> direst of emergencies, and as much as a Jedi survivor might make his
> old friend feel better, Bail knew it wasn’t worth the risk. Someday,
> if he had a reason to reach out, he would.
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

**So Obi-Wan intentionally avoided contact with Bail and other former acquaintances for fear of discovery.** The gaze of the Empire (and of the Emperor) was much heavier upon Bail, for example, than on Tatooine.

While Obi-Wan tried to avoid communicating with his friends, he was, as mentioned in the [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12406/51379), in communication with Qui-Gon’s force spirit.

> Obi-Wan let go of Ben Kenobi’s house, the last place in the galaxy
> where a piece of Anakin Skywalker rested, and broke through the wall
> between life and death. It was dark there if he wanted to take
> anything with him or leave anything behind, but he wished for neither
> of those things, so he stood in the light. His senses were sharp. He
> could hear every sound at once, and also none of them. It took him a
> moment to focus on the voice he wanted most to hear.
>
> Alone and connected. Aloof and hopelessly entwined. Obi-Wan had only a
> moment before he was wrenched back into the physical world, but it was
> long enough to renew his hope.
>
> “Obi-Wan,” said Qui-Gon Jinn. He was sure the voice was stronger this
> time. “Let go.”
>
> <sub>*Ahsoka*</sub>

As an additional note, it seems likely, based on recent revelations from *Star Wars: Rebels*, that Obi-Wan will be revealed to have had some contact with

> Darth Maul, now just Maul.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you're talking about canon, you're referring to canon under the new rules, where the previous "expanded universe" has been relegated to "Legends," so you mean canon now that it's in the Abramsverse, right?

Comment: @Tango - Yes, I mean Disney canon.

Comment: I'm changing this to my selected answer, but I think it might be appropriate to specify, in the answer, "Disney canon."  Do you mind editing it or mind if I edit and make that small change just for specificity?

Comment: I'm gonna have to sue Disney for losing all this valuable rep :(    Good find though, +1

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the living, but he most certainly communicated to Qui-Gon's Force Spirit (when learning how to become one himself), and presumably Qui-Gon's Force Spirit was in contact with Yoda, so this was at least one channel.

Comment: Isn't Qui-Gon's force spirit thing "redacted" to fit with the original trilogi? I always felt like it was slapped on there just as an explanation to how Obi-Wan and Yoda learned this particular trick. In fact, didn't they edit in Liam Neeson in the final scene of *Return of the Jedi*?

Comment: @TLP - yes, and yes. Nevertheless, Lucase says it's canon. The question wasn't "given only information from Ep4-6".

Comment: They didn't edit in Liam Neeson (not in any version I've seen, but I haven't seen the Blu-Rays). They did edit in Hayden Christiansen instead of Sebastian Shaw as the Anakin Force Ghost.

Comment: @KeithS Ah yes.

Comment: My sister has seen the blue rays and can confirm that they haven't gone that far, thankfully.

Comment: I just recently watched the blu-ray version.  No Qui-Gon in ROTJ.

Comment: Just to be clear, my "yes and yes" were (1) about the fact that Force Spirit is a retcon, and (2) is merely an explanation for OB1 to learn the trick. I also concur that there's no Qui-Gon in ROTK

Comment: If Qui-Gon appeared in the Return of the King we would all be worried.

Comment: @IanThompson - oupsie :)

Answer (score 0):

First, we know that Obi-Wan was communicating with Qui-Gon Jinn on Tatooine.  Second, the Emperor could sense "disturbances in the Force" which could also indicate that the more often that Obi-Wan used his Force powers, the more likely that his location might eventually be discovered by the Emperor. Once Obi-Wan received Leia's distress call from R2, he realized that he had to teach Luke the ways of the Force in order for the Rebel Alliance to have 'any chance' of defeating the Empire. So, I wouldn't say that Obi-Wan was "out of touch" with the people he knew, per se.